# Project structure for meson

Tags: linux, meson-build

With the following project structure

```
pj
|-src
   |-pj.c
   |-meson.build
|-meson.build
```

where pj/meson.build is

```
project('pj', 'c', version : '0.1')
subdir('src')
library('pj', sources : srcs)
```

and pj/src/meson.build is

```
srcs = 'pj.c'
```

then running

```
pj$ meson build
pj$ ninja -C build
```

gives the ninja error

```
File pj.c does not exist.
```

The only way I can get it to work is by setting pj/src/meson.build to

```
srcs='src/pj.c'
```

Easy enough when there's only 1 file but suppose there was 1,000.I found this earlier

[Meson targets that depend on subdir siblings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55107396/meson-targets-that-depend-on-subdir-siblings)

and I'd like to do it the way rellenberg's answer suggested however I can't see why my code won't work.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're using a plain string to enumerate your source files. It becomes clear when you just do a plain variable substitution in your toplevel meson.build: that now gives `library('pj', sources : 'pj.c')`, so Meson doesn't know about it.

To mitigate this, you can use the [`files()`](https://mesonbuild.com/Reference-manual_functions.html#files) function to enumerate your source files.

In other words, you can do the following:

```
srcs = files('pj.c')
# and later: files('pj1.c', 'pj2.c', ...)
```

And it will work again

Comment: Thanks. I hadn't noticed the files thing in the link I gave. Working now.